# How can I get Host:Port from all Spring Boot Instances registered at a Eureka Server?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, netflix-eureka

I have some spring-boot clients registered at an eureka server and I'd like to write a client that performs actions on all server instances e.g. call the health check.

Therefore I need all IPs and Ports but when I start the spring-boot instance with server.port=0 to be able to start multiple instances for loadbalancing the eureka api returns port 0 for all of the instances

```
List<String> apps = discoveryClient.getServices();  
             for (String app : apps ){
                     List<ServiceInstance> instances = this.discoveryClient.getInstances(app);
                        for (ServiceInstance instance : instances){
                            String url = "http://"+ instance.getHost() + ":"+ instance.getPort();
```

Also the eureka rest api returns the same

http://localhost:40001/eureka/apps

How can I get the correct ports on which the instances are started ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to set `eureka.instance.instance-id` to something that is unique. By default, that includes the port which means all of you instances have the same instance id.

Ideally you would use something other than `${random.int}` that the platform you are using provides you for uniqueness.

```
eureka:
  instance:
    instance-id: ${spring.application.name}:${random.int}
```

Comment: My configuration is

Comment: My conf is
server.port=0
eureka.instance.instanceId=poc-target-${random.int}

Log Files show
.s.c.n.e.s.EurekaAutoServiceRegistration : Updating port to 7404

.s.c.n.e.s.EurekaAutoServiceRegistration : Updating port to 10844

Eureka server shows both instances
eureka rest service returns

<instanceId>poc-target--1510941710</instanceId>
<port enabled="true">0</port>
<homePageUrl>http://xxx:0/</homePageUrl>

<instanceId>poc-target2--1120665828</instanceId>
<port enabled="true">0</port>
<homePageUrl>http://xxx:0/</homePageUrl>

Comment: Hard to read in a comment, you should put that in the question. I was unable to recreate your issue and had random ports register just fine in eureka. You'll need to provide a sample.

Comment: I'm afraid I'll need a minimal sample, without all the database and activemq stuff I don't have.

Comment: Seems to be caused by the zipkin / opentracing stuff .... when I remove the dependencies camel-opentracing-starter,brave-opentracing,zipkin-sender-urlconnection and the related code the ports are correctly in eureka.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the Spring documentation states that port=0 is really only intended for development purposes.

For micro-services (which is what Spring Boot is for), the whole point would be to have things on different servers/containers.
Which means each can have the same port (which is nice later because you can use well defined / common practice ports to remember what is what).

Just set real ports, because that is what you will do for production.

For development, that will still work because stuff will run on

- localhost:8000
- localhost:8001
- localhost:8002
- etc

The only case it won't is when you want to spin up 2 stacks at once.
For which you could either use containers (Docker,Vagrant, etc) or you can use Spring Profiles or Environment variables to specify the Spring property at runtime.

Comment: Spring Doc

73.3 Use a random unassigned HTTP port
To scan for a free port (using OS natives to prevent clashes) use server.port=0.

Server Port 0 makes sense if you want to scale with instances and set a ribbon loadbalancer 
to access the services

Comment: I still think its a bad idea for anything in production to be random. There are enough random things that happen in life. Might as well not manually add in one yourself :) For example, what if whatever hosting provider you use blocks a particular undocumented port for whatever reason and once in a blue moon Spring chooses that port?